# About memory alignment with Direct IO

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel

The linux kernel version is `4.15.0-47-generic` and the Block Size is `4096` via command `sudo /sbin/tune2fs -l /dev/sda1|grep "Block size"`.

I just wrote a DIRECT IO demo, code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    unsigned char *buf;
    ret = posix_memalign((void **)&buf, 512, BUF_SIZE);
    if (ret) {
        perror("posix_memalign failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buf, 'c', BUF_SIZE);

    fd = open("./direct_io.data", O_WRONLY | __O_DIRECT | O_CREAT, 0755);
    if (fd < 0){
        perror("open ./direct_io.data failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    do {
        ret = write(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("write ./direct_io.data failed");
        }
    } while (0);

    free(buf);
    close(fd);
}
```

My question:

> The `Block Size` is 4096, why the above demo in which `buf` address is 512 alignment, and `buf` size is multiple of 512 byte could run correctly. I have searched many information which say that the address and buffer size must be multiple of `Block Size`.

Comment: What is the type of `direct_io.data` file? Is it a character device  or a regular file? Can you please rewrite your question? `why the code which address` - you're code has an address? What do you mean by that? You mean that the address that is the entry to your function is aligned? I think you mean the address stored in `buf` is a multiple of 512. Why shouldn't it run correctly? How do you detect the `"could run correctly"` state? How do you detect error? Why is `Block Size` relevant to the question?

Comment: The [man open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is rather specific that `The
       logical block size can be determined using the ioctl(2) BLKSSZGET
       operation or from the shell using the command:

           blockdev --getss` I believe `tune2fs` queries the filesystem block size, not the blockdevice block size. Does `blockdev --getss /dev/sda1` also return 4096?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your comment, `blockdev --getss /dev/sda1` return `512`.

Comment: And man page states `Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size 
       of  the underlying storage (typically 512 bytes) suffices.`. What is your question?

Comment: I am a beginner of C programming, I will strengthen learning of c programming and improving my English skills.Thank you.